# Why can't I get protection 4 from the librarian in minecraft 1.18.2

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I tried trading with the librarian until it gets to tier 4 to see what enchanted books they have but if they don't have protection 4, then I move on to the next villager and protection 4 is not showing up.

Comment: You don't need to level up the villager. You can get any book, any enchantment level, in their first tier. (Well, except for the un-tradeables, such as Soul Speed or the new one in 1.19).

Answer (score 1):

This is just a question of time.
You can indeed get Protection IV from villagers.
I would suggest resetting a villager over and over instead of leveling him up to master. That way you can get to the specific trade you want, without wasting your precious ressources.

Process of resetting:

a) You need an unemployed villager

b) give him a workstation of your choosing (lecturn in this case)

c) check his trades.

d1) If the desired trade is offered,
take it. Once the villager gains exp his trades are locked.

d2) If the desired trade is not offered, remove the work station and wait until the villager is unemployed again. and go back to "b)"